# How can I set up a workflow email to send weekly with changes occuring past week?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

I know I am able to utilize a Sharepoint workflow when i need an email sent informing users of a change to a list or specific document. This email is sent as soon as something changes.

Is it possible to have sort of a delayed email? A customer wants only one email sent weekly with ALL changes/updates/deletions that had occured during the past week.

Thanks,
Ninel

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use an alert for this.  It will digest all of that automatically for you and allow you to send it on a weekly schedule to a particulr user or users.

Comment: I need to track changes that are made to multiple lists...one email to contain info on multiple lists.